# Post thats in Two Categories, only want to display name for one

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming, wordpress

In my Wordpress site I've created, I'm having issues hiding or not displaying one of the category titles I set up. I'll try to explain better.

**Wordpress Admin Side**

I have a post that is in two categories, a "`Work`" & "`Front_Page`"

**Main Page / index.php**

On my main index page, I have 3 features below the header image. One of those features is a "Featured Project". This is how I'm starting the loop...

```
    <? $frontpost = get_posts("category_name=front_page&numberposts=1");?>
```

**Single Project Page**

Now on this page, the visual layout is

Category Name

Which is called `<h2 class="single_category"><?=$cat[0]->name;?></h2>`

Project Title
Large Header Image
Project Desription

**THE PROBLEM!!!**

For whichever post I put in "`Front_Page`", it displays that in the Category Name. I want it to default to the main category.

Is there a way to basically say "if post is in "`front_page`" category, don't display "`front_page`" category as name?

Comment: try posting this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Ok, I am as we speak. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict whether to display the category name or not using in_category() .

```
<?php
   //if post is NOT in category 'front_page' display cat name
   if(!in_category('front_page')){?>
      <h2 class="single_category"><?=$cat[0]->name;?></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

You can place that in your single.php (or loop.php, depending on your theme) file in the area where you display the cat name.

I hope that helps!